# Unable to access fs module when using npm package in Meteor application

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, fs

I'm building a Meteor application, and I want to use the [docx-builder](https://github.com/raulbojalil/docx-builder) package to combine Word (.docx) documents stored on the server.

I installed the package using the following command:

```
meteor npm install --save docx-builder
```

On a template, I'm using the following code to try and create a document:

```
import builder from 'docx-builder';
var docx = new builder.Document();
docx.insertText('Hello World');
docx.save(__dirname + "/output.docx", function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

However, this is giving the following error:

```
[Error] TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function. (In 'fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/template.docx","binary")', 'fs.readFileSync' is undefined)
    save (modules.js:1272)
    program-details.js (app.js:2001)
    fileEvaluate (modules-runtime.js:343)
    Global Code (app.js:2944)
```

Clearly, there's something going wrong with the `fs` module that the package is trying to access. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you imported the module? `var fs = require("fs");`

Comment: @SamDenty I don't in my own template, but the package I'm using (docx-builder) does in it's index.js.